# 18.10 upgrade from 18.04 Graphics driver issues

Tags: nvidia, graphics, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-prime, 18.10

I recently upgraded my dell XPS 9570 from ubuntu 18.04 to ubuntu 18.10.
My laptop has a hybrid graphics system with an Nvidia 1050Ti  and intel graphics 630.
Since the upgrade, if the Nvidia graphics card is selected (with `prime-select`) I get a login loop or a freeze. If the intel graphics are selected, I can log in, but the screen resolution isn't recognized, and I have to fiddle with `xrandr` to get a usable resolution.
I have tried purging and re-installing the nvidia drivers on multiple versions: 390, 396 (the one that was working on 18.04), and 410 (latest available), But had no luck.

Any idea how I can fix that and use my graphics card?
Thanks

UPDATE: Problem fixed.
The issue came from the nvidia driver not being signed properly.
I found the following error in the system logs:
`PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key`
simply reinstalling the driver wasn't enough, I had to purge anything nvidia related and re install the driver and dependencies from scratch.

Comment: If you write out your fix as an answer, I'd mark it as +1.  I have exactly this issue today for the first time after updates. I see the XFCE picture to start, but when display manager tries to launch, I have black screen of death with only the messages about the "signature not signed with trusted key". I found only fix was reboot into recovery session as root and delete nvidia from command line.

Comment: I'd also be interested! I tried `apt purge nvidia-*` twice, no change; and even nouveau freezes for me ...

Comment: That wasn't enough for me either, I had to do `sudo apt list --installed | grep nvidia` to see everything nvidia that was installed, and remove as many as I could (some just wouldn't go away)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came from the nvidia driver not being signed properly. I found the following error in the system logs: PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key simply reinstalling the driver wasn't enough, I had to purge anything nvidia related and re install the driver and dependencies from scratch.

I had to go into recovery mode, and run:
`sudo apt purge nvidia-*`.
Then I ran `sudo apt list --installed | grep nvidia` to see if any more libraries were still installed and removed them with `sudo apt remove --purge <lib-name>`

Then I re-installed the nvidia driver, in my case with
`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-410` (check what the current version is when you do it)

Answer (score 0):

Try and uncomment WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and reboot.
I did this on my desktop w/Nvidia card and it allowed me to boot.  There are still random graphics problems when the computer wakes from sleep, but maybe you wont have those.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but didn't help. It's a bit worse, I can't get the display manager to load with the nvidia card.